# To get a specific line

Tags: bash

My `foo.txt` consists of,

```
Package: apt
Priority: important
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 3414
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Package: firefox
Priority: optional
Section: web
Installed-Size: 63988
Maintainer: Ubuntu Mozilla Team <ubuntu-mozillateam@lists.ubuntu.com>
Package: hostname
Priority: important
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 83
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
```

I want the pacakge name if it's corresponding pripority is important.If the column 2 in the line starting with the keyword `Priority` then display the line column2 of the line before the current line.

I tried this command,

```
awk '/^Priority && $2=="important"/ {print $0 }' ~/Desktop/awk
```

But it doesn't shows the current line also.It would be better if you provide the answer in awk.

Expected output:

```
apt
hostname
```

Comment: What do you mean with current line? To show `Package: apt`?

Comment: yes, the second field `apt` only if it satisfies the condition.

Comment: current line means that Priority line.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F' *: *' '$1=="Package"{p=$2;next} $1=="Priority"&&$2=="important"{print p}' file
apt
hostname
```

Comment: Sure. This awk used field separator regex as `' *: *' ` which means colons with 0 or more spaces on either side. Then it matches `Package` record and store its value in variable `p`. Further down when it matches `Priority: important` line it prints variable `p` value.

Comment: Please add the above comment in your answer.It would be helpful for me and others.

Comment: Nice explanation.And one more doubt, i want the package name which has the priority `important` or `required` then my command should be `awk -F' *: *' '$1=="Package"{p=$2;next} $1=="Priority"&&$2~(important|required){print p}' file`Am i correct?

Comment: Actually `$2~/(important|required)/` would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can place a regex between slashes, but you cannot use logical operators between slashes.

Try this:

```
awk -F": " '$1 ~ /^Priority/ && $2 == "important" {print last_value;} {last_value = $2;}' <your file>
```

Comment: Note the OP wants the previous line.

Comment: please explain a little bit about last_value.

Comment: Last value is the $2 of the previous line

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F': ' '/^Priority: important/ {print a} {a=$2}' foo.txt
```

Output:

```
apt
hostname
```

Explanation:

- `-F': '` sets the field delimiter to be a colon followed by a space.
- `awk` expects a *condition* followed by a *{statement}*, the condition `/^Priority: important/` matches lines that start with "Priority: important" and the following statement `{print a}` prints out the internal `awk` variable called `a`. So when the regex matches, `a` is printed.
- Lastly we have another *{statement}* but no condition - this assigns the 2nd field of the current line to `a`, since there is no condition, this will occur for all lines.

So when the regex doesn't match, `a` is set to the second field of the current line. When the regex matches, `a` is printed (containing the previous line) before it is set to the current line.

Comment: Please explain `{print a} {a=$2}` part.-F in awk means delimiter, so you gave the delimiter as `:` then this regex `/^Priority: important/` grabs the line starting with `Priority: important`.The $2 for the current line is important then how it prints the previous line's field no 2(apt)?

Comment: Edited answer to explain

Answer (score 1):

You can save the previous 2nd column, and when the line `Priority: important` is reached, print the previous value:

```
$ awk '/^Priority.*important/{print previous2}{previous2=$2}' foo.txt
apt
hostname
```